Issue with parserBuilder() method in JJWT library for JWT token validation
I'm currently working on a Spring Boot application that uses the JJWT library for JWT token validation. However, I am facing an issue with the parserBuilder() method. My goal is to parse and validate a JWT token using a secret key, but I'm encountering a compilation error that states: "The method parserBuilder() is undefined for the type Jwts."
Here’s a snippet of the code I’m working with:
 import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
 import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
 import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
 import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
 public class JwtTokenValidator {
    public Claims validateToken(String jwt) {
    SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor("mySecretKey".getBytes()); 
    Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(key)
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                        .getBody();
    return claims;
}}

`
Issues I’m Facing:

The error message states that parserBuilder() is undefined.
I want to ensure that I’m using the correct version of the JJWT library.

Additional Information:

I’m using version 0.12.6 of the JJWT library.
I’ve imported all the necessary classes from the JJWT package.

Questions:

What could be causing the "undefined" error for the parserBuilder() method?
Is there a correct way to parse and validate JWT tokens using the JJWT library that I might have missed?

I attempted to use the parserBuilder() method from the JJWT library to parse and validate a JWT token. I set up a SecretKey using Keys.hmacShaKeyFor() and called parserBuilder() on the Jwts class to create a parser, set the signing key, and parse the JWT. However, I encountered a compilation error stating: "The method parserBuilder() is undefined for the type Jwts," which prevented the code from compiling successfully. I expected the code to work without errors and for the Claims object to be returned properly.

parseBuilder was changed to parser() in 0.12 Version.
If you want it to work just change it to `parser():
Jwts.parser()
    .setSigningKey(key)
    .build()
    .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
    .getBody();

you will still have some deprecation notices though. Updated version for 0.12.6:

Jwts.parser()
    .verifyWith(key)
    .build()
    .parseSignedClaims(jwt)
    .getPayload();

